# Sort docs by inner field string

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming this is a mapping and person is the `type`:

```
{
    "person" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "first" : {"type" : "string"},
                    "last" : {"type" : "string"}
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

How can I sort the returned `person` documents by their last name? In `_search` query I try:

```
{
   "sort": [ {"name.last": "desc" } ]
}
```

---

Update **beware extremely long question**

@pickypg is absolutely right that the above works. So this is my more complex structure which does not. The mapping:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/venue/event/_mapping" -d '
{
    "event" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name"      : { "type"  : "string" },
            "address"   : { "type" : "string"},
            "_id"       : {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "$oid"      : { "type"  : "string" }
                }
            },
            "events"  : {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties": {
                    "event_id"       : {
                        "properties" : {
                            "$oid"      : { "type"  : "string" }
                        }
                    },
                    "title"         : { "type" : "string"}, 
                    "start_date"    : { "type" : "date" , "format": "basic_date_time_no_millis" }
                  }
            }

        }
    }
}'
```

What I get before I add documents on `venue/event/_mapping` (`_id` and `$oid` is missing):

```
{
    venue: {
        mappings: {
            event: {
                properties: {
                    name: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    address: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    events: {
                        properties: {
                            event_id: {
                                properties: {
                                    $oid: {
                                        type: "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            start_date: {
                                type: "date",
                                format: "basic_date_time_no_millis"
                            },
                            title: {
                                type: "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is an example document I insert (via bulk-feed: `helpers.bulk()` in elasticsearch-py):

```
{
    '_index': 'venue',
    '_type': 'event',
    '_id': '52cb45cfc36b444275172903',
    '_source': {
        'name': 'S.WalterStewartLibrary',        
        'address': '170MemorialParkAvenue',
        '_id': {
            '$oid': '52cb45cfc36b4442751728f9'
        },
        'events': {
            'title': u'ParentLedSingAlongGroup',
            'event_id': {
                '$oid': '52cb45cfc36b444275172903'
            },
            'start_date': u'2014-01-08T20: 15: 00+00: 00',           
        }
    }
}
```

What I get after I add documents on `venue/event/_mapping`. `$oid` has moved to the `_id`'s parent:

```
{
    venue: {
        mappings: {
            event: {
                properties: {
                    $oid: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    address: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    events: {
                        properties: {
                            event_id: {
                                properties: {
                                    $oid: {
                                        type: "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            start_date: {
                                type: "date",
                                format: "basic_date_time_no_millis"
                            },
                            title: {
                                type: "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    name: {
                        type: "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The query**:

This might work (because the sort in the results displays numbers):

```
GET venue/event/_search
{
   "size": 2,
   "sort": [
      {
         "name": "asc"
      }
   ]
}
```

result:

```
{
    "took": 11,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 10,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1000,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "venue",
                "_type": "event",
                "_id": "531de9d1c36b442c7cf79981",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Springville Moose Lodge 14141",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "531de9d0c36b442c7cf7997c"
                    },
                    "events": {
                        "title": "Community Meeting, Film Screening & Fish Fry",
                        "event_id": {
                            "$oid": "531de9d1c36b442c7cf79981"
                        },
                        "start_date": "2014-03-14T19:00:00-04:00"
                    }
                },
                "sort": [
                    "14141"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "venue",
                "_type": "event",
                "_id": "5303e066c36b4453b45fe459",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "AnCafe 173 Xuân Thủy",
                    "address": "173 Xuân Thủy",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5303e066c36b4453b45fe458"
                    },
                    "events": {
                        "end_date": "2014-03-01T10:00:00+00:00",
                        "title": "2014: Plans for WordPress in Vietnam",
                        "event_id": {
                            "$oid": "5303e066c36b4453b45fe459"
                        },
                        "start_date": "2014-03-01T08:00:00+00:00"
                    }
                },
                "sort": [
                    "173"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This definitely doesn't:

```
GET venue/event/_search
{
   "size": 2,
   "sort": [
      {
         "events.title": "asc"
      }
   ]
}
```

result (the sort is null):

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 10,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1000,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "venue",
                "_type": "event",
                "_id": "52e83eb6c36b4473d6c177ba",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Canadian Academic Succes School",                    
                    "address": "5310A Yonge Street",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "52cb45cec36b4442751728f6"
                    },
                    "events": {
                        "title": "Valentine's Party",
                        "event_id": {
                            "$oid": "52e83eb6c36b4473d6c177ba"
                        },
                        "start_date": "2014-02-16T01:00:00+00:00"
                    }
                },
                "sort": [
                    null
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "venue",
                "_type": "event",
                "_id": "52f70fa6c36b446c340e9374",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Canadian Academic Succes School",
                    "address": "5310A Yonge Street",
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "52cb45cec36b4442751728f6"
                    },
                    "events": {
                        "title": "English Circle 1 (With Brian)",
                        "event_id": {
                            "$oid": "52f70fa6c36b446c340e9374"
                        },
                        "start_date": "2014-02-10T00:00:00+00:00"
                    }
                },
                "sort": [
                    null
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using? And what happened? That works for me.

Comment: @pickypg 1.0.0. I try the above code and the documents return unsorted. If the field is only on the first level the sorting works e.g. `{"sort": [ {"another_field": "desc" } ]}`. Hmmm

Comment: Can you show an example document with example results? It worked perfectly for me in `v1.0.1`.

Comment: @pickypg You are very right. I added every step I do in my real data. I probably do something wrong in mapping declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_memory_considerations):

```
For string based types, the field sorted on should not be analyzed / tokenized.
```

So for strings that are more than one values long (e.g. a name `Sir Ker`) they should not be analyzed in order to get sorted. A good way is to use the new [copy_to](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#copy-to) and the new field have `"index": "not_analyzed"`

Example [based on this](http://blog.wiercinski.net/2011/uncategorized/elasticsearch-sorting-on-string-types-with-more-than-one-value-per-doc-or-more-than-one-token-per-field/):

```
curl -s -XGET 'es:9200/users/journalist/_mapping' 
{
    "journalist": {
         "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "copy_to" : "untouched_name"
                    }, 
                    "untouched_name": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed", 
                        "type": "string"
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

And then ask to sort the `untouched_name`.

But I think the best is with [fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_multi_fields_3):

```
"name": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "analyzed",
        "fields": {
           "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           }
        }
},
```

And sort: `name.raw: asc`

<s>Now I am searching how to sort `date` type fields. I will add more.</s>

It looks like that dates are fine and they do not need to be analyzed like strings do.

[One more interesting source from ES forum](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Sorting-failing-in-latest-master-td967979.html)